# GRUB2: When I choose Windows 8, error invalid EFI file path

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I had a problem with install Ubuntu 13.04 next to Windows 8. I have a Dell inspiron 15 notebook with UEFI.

In Boot-setup I changed to Legacy Boot on and switched UEFI boot off. Then I installed Ubuntu but the computer always starts Windows.

I have followed the instructions here : [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) but it hasn't helped.

I used [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and it helped; but It did not list Windows 8 in grub. Then I wrote with [QGRUBEditor](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/qgrubeditor-a-visual-grub-configuration-editor.html) Windows 8.

Now when I turn on my notebook in grub I have Windows 8 listed but if I choose it I get the error

```
Invalid EFI file path.
```

What can I do to fix this?

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: nieznany typ systemu plików ''

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda7 
                       and looks at sector 1565267170 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       in partition 94 for .
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 13.04
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

sda10: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
głowic: 255, sektorów/ścieżkę: 63, cylindrów: 121601, w sumie sektorów: 1953525168
Jednostka = sektorów, czyli 1 * 512 = 512 bajtów
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny) w bajtach: 512 / 4096

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,026,047     1,024,000 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,026,048     1,107,967        81,920 -
/dev/sda3       1,107,968     1,370,111       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda4       1,370,112     2,394,111     1,024,000 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda5       2,394,112   783,624,580   781,230,469 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda6   1,926,948,864 1,953,523,119    26,574,256 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda7     783,644,672 1,564,895,231   781,250,560 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda8     783,626,240   783,644,671        18,432 BIOS Boot partition
/dev/sda9   1,564,895,232 1,565,382,655       487,424 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda10  1,565,382,656 1,565,407,231        24,576 Swap partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        2081-D15D                              vfat       ESP
/dev/sda10       0610ae9a-1d01-413b-ac3d-0d9bfe8d5377   swap       
/dev/sda2        E0ED-C674                              vfat       DIAGS
/dev/sda4        981CEF4C1CEF244A                       ntfs       WINRETOOLS
/dev/sda5        5804F37604F3558A                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda6        768A92CB8A928771                       ntfs       PBR Image
/dev/sda7        bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048   ext4       
/dev/sda9        4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79   ext2       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw)
/dev/sda7        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda9        /boot                    ext2       (rw)


=============================== sda7/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda9 during installation
#UUID=4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=0610ae9a-1d01-413b-ac3d-0d9bfe8d5377 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79   /boot   ext2    defaults    0   2
UUID=2081-D15D  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda7: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

               =                initrd.img                                    68
               =                initrd.img.old                                68
               =                vmlinuz                                       24

============================= sda9/grub/grub.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=pl_PL
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048' {
recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
}
submenu 'Opcje zaawansowane dla systemu Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, za pomocą systemu Linux 3.8.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-advanced-bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 3.8.0-19-generic...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, za pomocą systemu Linux 3.8.0-19-generic (tryb ratunkowy)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-19-generic-recovery-bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4a8e05e5-da38-4b8d-a62b-7a65bac91c79
        fi
        echo    'Wczytywanie systemu Linux 3.8.0-19-generic...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic root=UUID=bbc0df4a-6a25-44fd-95c9-e358bfafe048 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Wczytywanie początkowego dysku RAM...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda9: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

               =                grub/grub.cfg                                  1
               =                initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic                   68
               =                vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic                      24

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown GPT Partiton Type
d3ad6b79bf6b9f4db631466eb71a4965
Unknown BootLoader on sda1

00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 08 3e 18  |.X.MSDOS5.0...>.|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 08 00 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 a0 0f 00 e1 03 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 5d d1 81 20 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..)].. NO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 44 69  |..............Di|
000001b0  73 6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72  ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73  |sk error...Press|
000001c0  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  20 74 6f 20 72 65 73 74  | any key to rest|
000001d0  61 72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |art.............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 01 7e 1b  |.X.MSDOS5.0...~.|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 a8 0f 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 40 01 00 41 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |.@..A...........|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 74 c6 ed e0 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..)t...NO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 44 69  |..............Di|
000001b0  73 6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72  ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73  |sk error...Press|
000001c0  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  20 74 6f 20 72 65 73 74  | any key to rest|
000001d0  61 72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |art.............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdb 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
```

Comment: I believe that if Windows 8 was installed in EFI mode then you change it to not EFI you have to reinstall Windows.  This question may help [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/107450)

Comment: Any answer is a guess at this point. Please post either the URL that Boot Repair provided or a pointer to the `RESULTS.txt` file that [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) generates. That will provide the information needed to provide advice without guessing.

Answer (score 1):

My "error invalid EFI file path" error was solved by install an alternative boot manager:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

http://ncu.dl.sourceforge.net/project/refind/0.7.5/refind_0.7.5-1_amd64.deb

PS:   My setup:  12.04.3 LTS amd64-desktop with BIOS set to "UEFI" mode.